# Determine the derivative of the integral?

Tags: calculus

So I'm working on some homework and honestly, I've no idea what I'm doing - I'm looking online for study material because I'm completely lost - I think I'm beginning to understand though, and want to check my work on an answer.  The problem is asking me to find the derivative of an integral - I presume I'm supposed to use the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus (which I think I understand) but I want to be sure.

In short, the problem is this:

Determine the derivative of the function:

$$\int_{0}^x \sqrt{1+\cos^2(t)}dt$$

The answer I got was: $\sqrt{1+\cos^2(x)}$

But I'm not entirely sure if it's correct (and I can't figure out a way to check it) could someone just tell me whether I'm on the right track or not?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the fundamental theorem of calculus is the right tool to use here.

Comment: Make sure all your conditions are satisfied in order to apply FTC.